# What happens on my node process when my mac go to sleep?

Tags: node.js, macos

I have a node crawler program, and I use it to detect broken links. When I wake my Mac up, I find this node process has used over 1G memory, but after a while, it resume to a normal value.

About my code, it just some network request and parsing the html page. I think my program keeps running after my mac slept because the process does not exit. But network is down (my IM is offline when mac slept), why request piling up (it looks like) instead of a network connection exception?

It confused my, and what happened when my Mac is sleeping?

Comment: no way to tell without seeing the code, and you telling us what you mean by "sleep" - there's many types of sleep that a pc/mac can be in. If your app keeps running, but the mac is sleeping, maybe the network's down, and your code just keeps piling up more and more outstanding crawl requests, which eventually get caught up on when the system wakes up.

Comment: Why you let your computer go to sleep when you want it to do something?

Comment: @ShanShan It will take a long time to finish the job, so my mac just sleep automatically.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment. I think my app keeps running while my mac is sleeping. I think your assumption maybe right, but why the request will pile up since the network is down? Why not the exception of network connection is thrown?

Comment: Why not just change your mac settings to not sleep if you want the process to run?

Comment: @Catfish Yes, it is the way to keep my process running, but I still don't understand what happened under the hood. Actually my program is running while my mac is sleeping, but why a network connection exception is not thrown and the request seems piling up.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact details, but i would never expect any process to keep running while a machine is asleep. If you need it to keep running, either change your sleep settings or move your code to a server or something that does not go to sleep.

Comment: In sleep mode, only the RAM is powered, no process is running. Did you ever try to write code while sleeping? What's happening is maybe an OSX bug or nodejs "bug" (the clock suddenly jumps few hours, imagine how a program would react to that).